# Execute code one step at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The below code won't populate the `NavigateUrl` property  because all the calculations (code execution) that should preceed that step won't finish. This could be related to the LINQ queries.

This is .NET 3.5, so no tasks are available.

I want each step to be completed before it moves to the next step. It seems the page submission finishes before waiting for all these steps to be completed. Should I use ado.net to fetch the data instead? Would the data retrieval be faster and allow this issue to be avoided?

```
int JobID = new SLICDataContext()
    .JobRequests
    .Where(x => x.JobRequestID == JobRequestID)
    .Select(x => x.JobID.GetValueOrDefault(0))
    .Single();

int reactiveJobId = new SLICDataContext()
    .Jobs
    .Where(x => x.JobID == JobID)
    .Select(x => x.ReactiveJobID.GetValueOrDefault(0))
    .Single();

lnkDocument.NavigateUrl = string.Format("/HeadOffice/ReactiveJobs/DocumentsUpload.aspx?ReactiveJobID={0}", reactiveJobId );
```

Comment: I don't see anything asynchronous here. Are you sure JobID isn't getting set? Try stepping through the code line by line in the debugger and watching what happens.

Comment: actually it should be reactivejobid instead of job id. but when i execute the code through line break all variables populates correctly. but when i remove the breaks i expect the pop up window to appear with navigateurl containing the above value.

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with the order of execution. But rather some issue with your popup. You should always work to isolate your issue so you know where it's occurring.

Comment: it is to do with order of execution, so for instance if i hard code the reactivejobid to lets say 123 the pop up will happen and the link will have url with 123 as query string value, so it seems when it looks by the time last line processes the code doesnt finish computing the ractivejobid

Comment: Again, doubt it's the order of code execution. I bet your Linq result isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: if i insert breakpoints i do get to see all variables populated correctly

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous or deferred in your code.  `Single()` will execute the query and return the result before moving to the next statement.  Either you've got something asynchronous somewhere else or you're not getting the results you expect back.

Comment: I doubt it will make a difference, but you might try using one context instead of creating a new one for each query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this behave differently?

It's also unclear why the population of `reactiveJobId` even occurs; you don't use it in your string format, and doesnt' appear to have any meaningful side-effects.

```
using (var db = new SLICDataContext())
{
    int JobID = db
    .JobRequests
    .Single(x => x.JobRequestID == JobRequestID)
    .JobID.GetValueOrDefault(0);

    int reactiveJobId = db
    .Jobs
    .Single(x => x.JobID == JobID)
    .ReactiveJobID.GetValueOrDefault(0);

    lnkDocument.NavigateUrl = 
      string.Format("/HeadOffice/ReactiveJobs/DocumentsUpload.aspx?ReactiveJobID={0}",
                    JobID);

}
```

Comment: i was meant to use reactivejobid instead, updated question to reflect that. let me try your code

Comment: Won't `.Single` return a single `JobRequest`, which (presumably) you won't be able to call `.Select` on? I'm thinking this won't compile.

Comment: i used SingleOrDefault() it compiled but the reactivejobid variable only gets populated with break points, strange ill transfer it to another page and try getting the reactivejobid from that page